# How to add javascript and css to a SharePoint 2010 webpart?

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, css

What is the proper way (i.e. without having to manually copy the assets to any sharepoint folder or anything like that) to add custom javascript and CSS to a SP 2010 web part?

I would like them to be a part of the solution so that I don't have to deploy the solution and remember to copy/remove files anywhere.

**Edit:** If possible, please describe how to do that both in sandbox and non-sandbox solutions.

Answer (score 6):

If you're deploying the web part as part of a .wsp deploy the files to a mapped folder like `_layouts` as part of the solution. Just right click on the project in Visual Studio and click Add > SharePoint "Layouts" Mapped Folder. Then put the files you need in that folder and they'll be deployed during the solution install.

Comment: Then you can reference them with a relative url, eg: "_layouts/myscript.js"

Comment: Does this mean it cannot be a sandbox solution? If yes, is there a way to achieve this in a sandbox solution?

Comment: http://www.christianfredh.com/blog/post/SharePoint-2010-Sandbox-Solutions-and-Visual-Studio-2010-Project-Templates.aspx according to this, not via this method.

Answer (score 3):

Just use modules to add your assets (css and javascript). The best way to learn how to do, read [Thomas Balkeståhl's blog](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/04/04/spb-usage-guide-2-configuration-and-modification/).

[image]

And [download his Visual Studio template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=User&f%5B0%5D.Value=Thomas%20Balkest%C3%A5hl) and create your solution from his template.

Answer (score 2):

For **non-sandbox** solution you can add JS and CSS files in the **Layout mapped folder** then use the *SharePoint:ScriptLink* tag for **javascript** files:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLink1" runat="server" Localizable="false" Name="projectname/some-js-file.js" />
```

where the path `projectname/some-js-file.js` is inside the Layout folder.

For **css** files use the *SharePoint:CssRegistration* tag instead:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" runat="server" Name="/_layouts/projectname/some-css-file.css" />
```

See here for more details:
http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/06/19/include-javascript-and-css-files-in-your-sharepoint-2010-visual-web-part/

Answer (score -2):

You can add Javascript using sandbox soltuion to one of your libraries. I have recently add JQuery library. Here are the steps from my blog post

http://preachingsharepoint.blogspot.ca/2012/05/add-jquery-to-office-365-sharepoint.html

Comment: Since your blog post is just a few lines please just paste your content here and add a link to your blog for reference if it adds value. That way the content is here to help visitors, whereas links go stale. And you'll probably get upvotes instead of downvotes ;-)